# Create formula field that will show Email of the User in your layout when you will create a new record

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I want to Create formula field that will show Email of the User in your layout when you will create a new record

Can anyone help to how should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do you want the Email Address of the current user or the user that created the record?  Either way it isn't a difficult formula.  Just create a formula field of type text and then insert the field you want.

For the Current User:

```
$User.Email
```

For the User that Created the record:

```
CreatedBy.Email
```